# C# Dynamic Order By Depending on Method Parameter

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a method like below ->

```
public static IOrderedQueryable<PurchaseOrder> GetOrders(bool ascending,string orderByField, IQueryable<PurchaseOrder> purchaseOrders)
{
        
        switch (orderByField)
        {
                case "OrderNumber":
                    return ascending ? purchaseOrders.OrderBy(x => x.OrderNumber) :
                                            purchaseOrders.OrderByDescending(x => x.OrderNumber);


                case "DeliveryDate":
                    return ascending ?
                                         purchaseOrders.OrderBy(x => x.DeliveryDate) :
                                         purchaseOrders.OrderByDescending(x => x.DeliveryDate);
                default:
                    return ascending ?
                                         purchaseOrders.OrderBy(x => x.OrderDate) :
                                         purchaseOrders.OrderByDescending(x => x.OrderDate);
        }
}
```

I want to dynamically order "purchaseOrders". Somthing like

```
purchaseOrders.OrderBy(orderByField) OR OrderByDescending(orderByField) //this is just an idea what is want to do.
```

After that I want to move the code part

```
ascending ? purchaseOrders.OrderBy(x => x.OrderNumber) :
                                            purchaseOrders.OrderByDescending(x => x.OrderNumber);
```

Inside a method and I can reuse it.
Is there any way to do that?
If any then please let me know.

**Note:** If any code create any confusion please let me know.

Comment: Not unless you want to deal with Expressions directly.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41244/dynamic-linq-orderby-on-ienumerablet-iqueryablet?

Comment: Thank you @EtiennedeMartel it might work for me let me check